# What's the point of {0} placeholder

Tags: python, django, tostring

So I'm currently going through an django+angular tutorial, and in it, one of my model's `unicode` function is this

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '{0}'.format(self.content)
```

My question is why is this necessary to use this placeholder? Could i have not just done this and achieve the same result?

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.content
```

`content` is a TextField

Comment: `return '{0}.format(self.content)'` is not the same as `return '{0}'.format(self.content)`, possible typo here.

Comment: In your case, you can just use `return self.content`, we use `format()` when we need to inject some values in a another string like `'Hello {}'.format(name)`

Comment: You are really not asking about a *placeholder* per se. You are asking why you cannot return `self.content` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Technically a class can choose to be formatted however it wants:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __format__(self, format_spec):
...         return 'foo'
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'bar'
...         
>>> str(A())
'bar'
>>> '{0}'.format(A())
'foo'
```

[Here are some tasty docs.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__)

Answer (score 0):

The reason of using `.format()` in this case is to always return the value of `content` in the form of string, no matter what it holds. For example:

```
>>> '{0}'.format(1)   # `int`
'1' 
>>> '{0}'.format(1.01)  # `float`
'1.01'
>>> '{0}'.format(u'Hello')  # `unicode string`
'Hello'
```

Without that, you will end up sending the same value preserving the type of actual `content`.

---

**Note:** My answer assumes that there is typo in the question and you meant `'{0}'.format(self.content)` instead of `'{0}.format(self.content)'`